# Error: No matching function for call to constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm learning oop in c++ and have the following error:

> In constructor 'pflFr1::pflFr1()'
>
> Error: No matching function for call to worldBuilder::worldBuilder()

The class worldbuilder is generating protected 2d arrays. The class pflfr1 is inherting from worldbuilder. But somehow, the constructor of worldbuilder has a problem.

My code:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pflfr1.h"
#include "worldbuilder.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int sl = 10;

    worldBuilder w_obj(sl);
    w_obj.buildPhyWelt();
    w_obj.buildVegWelt();
    pflFr1 objekt();
    return 0;
}
```

**worldbuilder.h:**

```
#ifndef WORLDBUILDER_H
#define WORLDBUILDER_H
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class worldBuilder
{
    public:
        worldBuilder(int sl_);
        vector<vector<int> > buildPhyWelt();
        vector<vector<int> > buildVegWelt();
    protected:
        vector<vector<int> > phyWelt;
        vector<vector<int> > vegWelt;
        int sl;
    private:
};

#endif // WORLDBUILDER_H
```

**worldbuilder.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "worldbuilder.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

worldBuilder::worldBuilder(int sl_)
: sl(sl_)
{

}

vector<vector<int> > worldBuilder::buildPhyWelt()
{
    phyWelt.resize(sl, vector<int>(sl));

    // initialisiere physische Welt
    // 1 = land, -1 ist meer
    for(int i=0; i<sl; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<sl; j++)
        {
            phyWelt[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

vector<vector<int> > worldBuilder::buildVegWelt()
{
    vegWelt.resize(sl, vector<int>(sl));

    // initialisiere Nahrung
    for(int i=0; i<sl; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<sl; j++)
        {
            if(rand()%100<=2)
            {
                vegWelt[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                vegWelt[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**pflfr1.h:**

```
#ifndef PFLFR1_H
#define PFLFR1_H
#include <vector>
#include "worldbuilder.h"

using namespace std;

class pflFr1: protected worldBuilder
{
    public:
        pflFr1();
    protected:
    private:
        int y;
        int x;
        int hp;
};
#endif // PFLFR1_H
```

**pflfr1.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pflfr1.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

pflFr1::pflFr1()
: hp(10)
{
    int initPosY = rand()%sl;
    int initPosX = rand()%sl;

    y = initPosY;
    x = initPosX;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` - That's a *very bad* thing to do in a header file.

Comment: The default constructor is not generated automatically if there is another constructor( which you have).

Comment: I have an advice, use variable names that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your default constructor `pflFr1::pflFr1()` 's implementation is rewritten as

```
pflFr1::pflFr1()
: worldBuilder(), hp(10){
    ...
}
```

Because the `pflFr1` class derives from `worldBuilder`, its constructor must be called as part of `pflFr1` object creation. The default behaviour is to call the default constructor of the base - `worldBuilder()`.

But this constructor does not exist. You only declared `worldBuilder::worldBuilder(int sl_);`. By doing so you disabled the automatic generation of default constructors for classes, which is done only if no user-defined constructor was declared.

Either you can write `worldBuilder()=default;` inside the class, which will leave  `s1` uninitialized. Or you can use delegating constructors -  `worldBuilder():worldBuilder(0){}`.

Comment: Or the initial value (0) could be specified explicitly in the initializer list of `pflFr1::pflFr1`. (Maybe there is a value that works for `pflFr1` but not for other classes derived from `worldBuilder`?)